# How to Replace Text With Split (_)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this code:

```
str1 = str1.replace(/_A/g, '<span>A</span>');
```

But it was too bad to replace a lot of different words.

So, I have a sentence that there is `(_)` behind the letter. For example `_A _B _C`
Well, is there a simple way to change that?

For example, `_A` replaced with `<span>A</span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`\w+` for word match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) in regex and add modifier `g` for the global match.

```
str1 = str1.replace(/_(\w+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'); // use captured value within the replace pattern
```

```js
var str = '_A _B _C';
console.log(str.replace(/_(\w+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'))
```

---

**UPDATE :** To match the string like `_A/B` and `_A#B` you need to use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with those special symbols.

```
str1 = str1.replace(/_([\w\/#]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'); // use captured value within the replace pattern
```

```js
var str = '_A _B _C _A/B  _A#B';
console.log(str.replace(/_([\w\/#]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'))
```

---

**FYI :** The `\w` also includes `_` if you want to avoid that then use negated character class `[^\W_]` instead

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But there is a new problem. How to change this code `_A/B` and `_A#B` Sorry if too many questions :)

Comment: @satriabajakan : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the modifiers:

```
str1 = str1.replace(/_(.*)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

You need to be careful with this as it would take everything till the end.

```js
$(function () {
  $("ul li").each(function () {
    $(this).html(function () {
      return $(this).text().replace(/_(.*)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
li span {background: #eee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>_A</li>
  <li>_B</li>
  <li>CD</li>
  <li>_E</li>
  <li>_FG</li>
</ul>
```

If they are mixed up, you can use the `(\w+)` word selector instead of `(.*)`
 greedy match.