# How to Delete All Text Specific Use CSS?

Tags: css

I made a few posts on the blog with additional special characters. For example like this `@A @B @C`
Initially, I change all the text that there is a sign `@` into a tag using javascript. Being a `<span class='a'>A</span>`

But after I thought about it, it will not work for many mobile platforms. Especially that does not use a script.

So I thought it would look bad if the character appears as the original. Now, is there a way to change that?

Could it be that I can do that with the

`<noscript>
<style> @{display:none} </style>
</noscript>`

Hassle here because the code is not in any tag...

Comment: Why are those special characters there in the first place…?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is your blog using some CMS? Can't the CMS do what you need? Seems to me you are trying to do something that should be done in the backend.

Comment: No, this is not possible with CSS. CSS only styles elements...no separate characters in an element.

Comment: @deceze To change all the text behind it. Previously I've asked this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635810/how-to-replace-text-with-split/40635854

Comment: Why is this happening client side instead of in a server-side template processor?